# Negative pressure experiments

Tags: condensed-matter

One method of understanding the physics of materials is to study their properties under the effect of pressure. Under high pressure, new phases can arise. Experimentally, high pressure can be obtained using an anvil press.

Are there experiments done in the negative pressure regime? If so, how is negative pressure obtained experimentally? Are there any noteworthy results?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are. Among normal matter, only solids and liquids can sustain negative pressure.

For solids we can shape the material like a 3D cross and pull in three directions at once.

We can also do it in lqiuids. Here is a discussion for negative pressure, as in below-vacumn pressure, in liquids:

http://discovermagazine.com/2003/mar/featscienceof

This is somewhat unstable: a tiny gap in the liquid can break the seal, much like lifting one side of a suction cup, and the liquid will "cavitate". The needed gap size decreases with increasing tension, and for negative pressures in trees it is microscopic.

In both solids and liquids the amount of negative pressure is limited by the tensile strength of the material. Pull too hard and the material will break, creating regions of vacuum (or vapour) that allow an arbitrarily large volume increase. Impurities lower the amount of negative pressure that can be supported.

Positive pressure has no such limit: you can keep cramming more and more material into a given volume to ramp up the pressure.